# How to transform Excel Data

Tags: excel

I have data coming into Excel (from external source) that looks like:

```
**Column A**          **Column B**
6/26/2017             null
Temperature           27
Pressure              5
6/27/2017             null
Temperature           29
Pressure              4
```

I would like to have it like this:

```
**Column A (Date)**          **Column B (Temp)**          **Column C (PSI)**
6/26/2017                    27                           5
6/27/2017                    29                           4
```

Since the data comes in via 'Refresh All', how can I take that and push it to columns like this?

Comment: How many column B's does your worksheet have?

Comment: Obviously that was a mistake.  Thanks for pointing it out.. Corrected.

Comment: When you say "data coming from an external source", what do you mean exactly? Are you getting a CSV file? Are you connecting to a database in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure of the periodicity of your data, you may use the `OFFSET` [function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324991/how-to-use-the-offset-function-in-excel).

- Add an auxiliary column with an crescent index;
- fill the "column date" with `=OFFSET($A$1; ($E2-1)*3; 0)`, where:

  - A1 refers to your first cell in your external data (*6/26/2017*)
  - E2 refers to your index, the cell where my function was applied being F2

Answer (score 0):

If to be 'pushed' you would need something like VBA, though is possible with a formula (in C2, copied across to D2 and the pair copied down to suit):

```
=OFFSET(A2,1,1)
```

but that would then need to be converted to Values (eg with Paste Special) if the surplus column and rows are to be deleted. And this would not 'refresh' as easily as say a PivotTable.

Answer (score 0):

Try working from the last date to the top.

```
Dim i As Long

With Worksheets(4)
    For i = Application.Match(1E+99, .Range("A:A")) To 1 Step -3
        .Cells(i, "C") = .Cells(i + 2, "B").Value
        .Cells(i, "B") = .Cells(i + 1, "B").Value
        .Cells(i + 1, "A").Resize(2, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i
    .Cells(1, "A").EntireRow.Insert
    .Cells(1, "A").Resize(1, 3) = Array("**Column A (Date)**", "Column B (Temp)", "**Column C (PSI)**")
End With
```